# Is it a correct construction "do something without somebody doing something"?

Tags: sentence-construction

For example, I wrote the sentance:

> Any program that is able to answer the questions meaningfully and keep the conversation going without people guessing it’s an AI is a human-like one.

Firstly, I wonder if it's correct. Secondly, it would be very nice of you to show a few more constructions with a close meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in the question is grammatical. It seems natural and I have no trouble understanding it (but then I am very familiar with the Turing Test).

Sentences using a similar structure would include:

> - When the pitcher throws the ball through the strike zone without the batter hitting it, the pitch is a strike.
> - When Congress passes a Bill without the President exercising the veto power, the bill becomes a law.
> - Any player who bids seven and plays the hand without the opponents taking any tricks scores a grand slam.

Note that often such sentences can be recast into a form that does not use 'without".

In the original sentence, the referent of the pronoun "it" (in the contraction "it's") is "Any program". This is rather far from the pronoun, and a user could be confused as to what the referent is. The sentence could be recast to not use a pronoun in that spot, or to move the pronoun clsoer to the referent.

You write "I wonder if it's correctly", but this is not correct. It should either be "I wonder if it's correctly **formed**." (or "written" or some similar verb) or else "I wonder if it's **correct**."  "Correctly" is an adverb and must modify a verb.

Also it would be more natural to write "show a few more" or "show several more" than "show a bit more" in this situation.